# Favicon Not working in Internet Explorer, How to fix it?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, favicon

I have checked all solutions provided on stack overflow but i could not solve my issue that is favicon not showing in IE.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon1.ico" >
    <link rel="icon" type="/image/ico"  href="favicon1.ico" >
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

png file which converted and being used as .ico file [I could not upload .ico file here]:

[image]

Can anyone help how to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### this worked for me

open site in IE 
go to 
settings -> Compatibility View Settings 
add that site 
and reload

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/png">
```

favicon.ico and html page are same directory

Comment: He can *not* ask to each visitor to change their settings ;)

Comment: He *could* ask each visitor to change settings.  He just wouldn't be very popular.  :-)

Comment: if href contains an .ico file, then type should probably be "image/x-icon" as the corresponding media type, or be omitted altogether. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a site like http://www.favicon-generator.org/ to generate png files and have the good syntax.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon1.ico" >
<link rel="icon"          href="favicon1.ico" type="image/ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png"  type="image/png">
```

You can send more information like size :

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32"    href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96"    href="/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16"    href="/favicon-16x16.png">
```

If you can not upload ico file, don't mention it and let only this line :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png"  type="image/png">
```